# Git Deletion not Detected

Tags: git

I'm having an issue with Git not detecting the deletion of a specific file in our repository.

The deleted file is `app/Enums/CostEstimate/PositionType.php`. When I check this with `git log --summary --follow -- app/Enums/CostEstimate/PositionType.php`, it shows only a 'create' operation and no 'delete' operation.

The file is indeed not present in my working directory. Also `git status` isn't showing the deletion as an uncommitted change.

I also pulled that branch from the remote, so the problem does not only exist on my computer.

Further analysis with various commands (like git diff, git log, etc.) and through my IDE + `gitk` doesn't show any delete operation for this file. Yet, the file is not present in my work tree. This situation is highly unusual and unexpected.

`origin/develop` was recently merged into the feature branch and before that a squashed merge was done into `origin/develop` - can this be the cause of the problem?

`git log -- app/Enums/CostEstimate/PositionType.php` shows only a 'create' operation

```
$ git clone ...

$ git checkout feature-branch

$ git log --summary --follow -- app/Enums/CostEstimate/PositionType.php
commit 270919558c9d278b72b3cc6ebe83fc8d066fb854
Author: x
Date:   Thu Oct 26 12:11:19 2023 +0200

    ... commit message ...

 create mode 100644 app/Enums/CostEstimate/PositionType.php

$ cat app/Enums/CostEstimate/PositionType.php
cat: app/Enums/CostEstimate/PositionType.php: No such file or directory

$ git status
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

We were able to recover the situation by recreating the branch and cherry picking the commits into a new one - so the motivation for my question is to understand `git` better for future situations like this.

EDIT as per comment:

```
$ git log --name-status 270919558c9d278b72b3cc6ebe83fc8d066fb854..HEAD -- app/Enums/CostEstimate/PositionType.php
*Empty output*
```

EDIT2

```
git merge-base  270919558c9d278b72b3cc6ebe83fc8d066fb854 HEAD
270919558c9d278b72b3cc6ebe83fc8d066fb854
```

EDIT3:

```
git ls-tree -r HEAD app/Enums/CostEstimate/PositionType.php
*Empty output*
```

EDIT4:

```
$ git ls-tree -r  270919558c9d app/Enums/CostEstimate/PositionType.php
100644 blob a60e55681c97e1ae3ca6f84a8d656e18625b89da    app/Enums/CostEstimate/PositionType.php
```

Comment: Are you in a commit _behind_ the commit where the file is added? If the answer is _not_ then the file had to be removed somewhere in the range `commit-where-it-was-added..HEAD`. `git log --name-status the-commit-where-it-was-added..HEAD -- the-file`  should show you where it happened.... there's also the possibility that the file was renamed, of course.

Comment: I am not 100% sure if I am behind or ahead that commit. But I executed the command you suggested and updated the question. It does not display output

Comment: Oh well.... to figure out if you are ahead or behind the commit where the file is added (if you find it too cumbersome for whatever reason), then you can check this: `git merge-base the-commit-where-it-was-added HEAD`. If the result is the commit id where you are, then you are behind.... if the result is the commit ID of the commit where the file was added, then you are ahead of that commit.... if it's a different commit, then you have _diverged_ and it might be the case that the file is not in the history of the commit you are on.

Comment: Question updated - Looks like I am ahead - does that mean the file simply was not yet merged into my branch? Or where is front and where is back ;-) ? *head spinning around*

Comment: What happens if you run `git ls-tree -r HEAD app/Enums/CostEstimate/PositionType.php`

Comment: To answer your question from the comment: Nope.... it's not about the branch being merged or not. The commit where the file is added is already part of the history of the commit that you are on.... so the file was there at least at a certain point in _your_ history. The last command I asked to run (`git ls-tree`) is to check that the file _is_ in the _current_ commit itself (regardless of it showing up in the working tree or not).

Comment: Updated, also had a longer call with a colleague .. we are merging back and that might have caused the problem.

Comment: Ok, good luck! If it's not a problem for you, can you provide this output? `git ls-tree -r  270919558c9d app/Enums/CostEstimate/PositionType.php`.

Comment: At this point and given that normal tools to see what is going on have failed, I would consider doing a bisect to see in what commit it disappeared.... The file is there: `good`. The file is not there: `bad`

Comment: I don’t see why `git log --all -- app/Enums/CostEstimate/PositionType.php` shouldn’t be enough to give an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm having an issue with Git not detecting the deletion of a specific file in our repository.

and:

> The file is indeed not present in my working directory. Also, git status isn't showing the deletion as an uncommitted change.

You can only delete a file (with git) that existed (in git).

If the path of history has no removal of the file (but you're able to locate some revision that added it): it means that from the current point in time/history you're looking from, the file has not been added yet.

This may sound contradicting (as much as the earlier sentences sounded crystal clear), but this can indeed happen when a merge (and then most often over multiple merges) went wrong.

For example, previewing the diff of a merge (with more than one parent) shows the file is being removed *despite* there is no commit that removes it.

Let's see what you wrote about the merge/s:

> `origin/develop` was recently merged into the feature branch and before that a squashed merge was done into `origin/develop` - can this be the cause of the problem?

Just to get this out of the way upfront: squashed merges are normally not the cause of such problems. A squash merge either has the deleting or the adding as it is a single commit with a single parent commit. This also makes them easy to review afterwards.

However, with a non-squashed merge, if the base of the feature branch was different — e.g. before adding the file — and there are other merges here and there in-between and then with the merge from `origin/develop` into the feature branch there is a path the file was never added (which must be the case as it was never deleted, e.g. the original base of the feature branch) then merging the feature branch later back into `origin/develop` can lead into merging that segment of the history where the file was never added.

This can result in what you describe: No file, but added and just not there!

Always review the merge result prior merge and if it makes no sense at all (like how you describe it), do not merge as obviously this is not what the intention was.

This is how you describe how you could help yourself:

> We were able to recover the situation by recreating the branch and cherry picking the commits into a new one - so the motivation for my question is to understand git better for future situations like this.

Now we don't have all the specifics at hand, but this sounds like a good approach to me as it is fixing the problem before it is going into your main line (e.g. the `origin/develop` branch from your description).

Creating a branch with a new name to cherry-pick from the old, "bad" branch also makes you normally choose the right base and to keep any merges out of the feature branch.

This is effectively "rebasing" the feature branch, and it's much better to understand as cherry-picking is more interactive, and you can do it for one commit after the other. It is also possible to cherry-pick a range of commits at once — see git-cherry-pick(1) and look for two dots — especially if any of those picked commits are without any conflicts. Mind thought it is not from-to but one-before-from-to; the manpage should explain this much better than I could do in this answer.

And do not cherry-pick any merge commits. You want to get rid of them; this is why you choose the correct base for the new branch in the first place.

So when done, you've experienced what actually happens during an (interactive) rebase, so this can also be a good learning experience as it is sometimes mystified; and cherry-picking on a new branch is without any magic, that magic which can often lead to wrong understanding, .e.g. what happens if you miss a commit? The new branch shows you the clear picture and previewing the diff of the merge directly shows if the problem was addressed.

---

After you've solved the puzzle, an interesting further reading in this context may be [Should developers merge code across branches?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/335840/440297) on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com).